# Does mozillas firefox countless versions make GWT development impossible?

Tags: firefox, gwt

There was no GWT plugin for firefox 6 and likely there won't be a release for firefox 7, because firefox 8 is already in beta. How can I develop a GWT app, when mozilla releases one firefox version after another? How can I ensure browser compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been happy so far staying a version behind in Firefox for the plugin, and using compiled code for tests in newer versions.  There is now an automatic update for the gwt plugin for Firefox 6, so someone is keeping *something* updated.

PS: I've yet to notice a single-pixel difference in firefox rendering between recent versions!

Answer (score 1):

It does not make it impossible, it just makes it equivalent to regular development.  You can still test it on the latest version of Firefox, as well as the other platforms for which the GWT plugin is available.  Beta versions of browsers, latest versions (which do not yet have GWT plugins released), and obscure browsers will just need to be tested manually.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are impatient to wait for an official release, you can download a prebuilt from the code repository. It does the job with Firefox 7.

[GWT Plugin Prebuilt at Google Code](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/xpcom/prebuilt/)